# Is it possible to fly stand-by on international flights at Tokyo Narita airport with JAL?

Tags: nrt, standby, jal

Anybody has and experience in stand-by (looks like they don't use the word stand-by, instead it's called `空席待ち` in Japanese FYI) at Tokyo Narita with `Japan Airlines (JAL)`?
[I've tried to look up online](https://www.google.co.jp/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ana+%E7%A9%BA%E5%B8%AD%E5%BE%85%E3%81%A1+%E6%88%90%E7%94%B0+%E5%9B%BD%E9%9A%9B%E7%B7%9A&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=KMIjV5qNOIyL8QetkoSgDg#channel=fs&q=jal+%E7%A9%BA%E5%B8%AD%E5%BE%85%E3%81%A1+%E6%88%90%E7%94%B0+%E5%9B%BD%E9%9A%9B%E7%B7%9A) about how they handle stand-by for international flights at Narita, but no info came up so far.

[This one explains (in Japanese)](http://air.tabiris.com/waiting.html) how another company in Japan (Skymark) handles that, but not JAL.

By the way, with the other major airline company in Japan, `ANA`, [I don't find any sound info online](https://www.google.co.jp/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ana+%E7%A9%BA%E5%B8%AD%E5%BE%85%E3%81%A1+%E6%88%90%E7%94%B0+%E5%9B%BD%E9%9A%9B%E7%B7%9A&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=KMIjV5qNOIyL8QetkoSgDg#) either.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know ?

Comment: 1) whether `JAL` does "stand-by" at NRT for the international flight (, which I'll ask them by calling today daytime) 2) If they do then best practice if any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asked [JAL customer support](https://www.jal.co.jp/information/inter/). They do not offer at Narita an equivalent service as `stand-by` in the American sense; Basically you need to already have purchased a ticket to pass the security zone and proceed to gates.

Comment: It does largely depend on the individual situation. I know they offer standby if you have missed a flight due to your own fault or fault of the airline and have either been rebooked or a new ticket purchased, have an emergency requirement to travel (ie. sickness, death in the family) or are travelling on staff travel. In all of these cases, as you state, you would have had to have passed through the security gate (which requires a boarding pass or staff card).